# ¿porqué no puedo pasar parámetros a mi JasperReports?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Buen día, tengo el siguiente código que genera un reporte de venta:

```
public void ReporteVenta() throws SQLException,JRException, ClassNotFoundException{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proyecto7c", "root", "*****");
        JasperReport report;
        report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile("C:\\Users\\pc\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\proyecto7mo\\src\\Reportes\\ReporteVentas.jasper");
        JasperPrint im=JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,null,conexion);
        JasperViewer ver=new JasperViewer(im);
        ver.setTitle("Ticket de venta");
        ver.setVisible(true);
    }
```

Eso funciona correctamente, ahora, mi problema es que cuando trato de crear un reporte con parámetros, el IDE me arroja el siguiente "error":

```
 > no suitable method found for
    > fillReport(JasperReport,Map<String,String>,Connection)
    >     method JasperFillManager.fillReport(String,Map<String,Object>,Connection) is
    > not applicable
    >       (argument mismatch; JasperReport cannot be converted to String)
```

Y lo único que cambié en el código es agregar un Map para los parámetros, y se lo estoy pasando en el método `fillreport` de la siguiente manera:

```
public void ReporteVenta(String idVenta) throws SQLException,JRException, ClassNotFoundException{
        Map<String, String> parametros;
        parametros = new HashMap<>();
        parametros.put("IdVenta", idVenta);
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        Connection conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proyecto7c", "root", "****");
        JasperReport report;
        report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile("C:\\Users\\pc\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\proyecto7mo\\src\\Reportes\\ReporteVentas_1.jasper");
        JasperPrint im;
        im = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report,parametros, conexion);//aquí me muestra ese mensaje
        JasperViewer ver=new JasperViewer(im);
        ver.setTitle("Ticket de venta");
        ver.setVisible(true);
    }
```

*¿qué necesito cambiar para que pueda realizar el reporte?* Aclaro, la conexión a la base de datos esta bien y ya agregué el parámetro que deseo a mi reporte.
Estoy siguiendo [Este tutorial](http://www.javatutoriales.com/2009/03/creacion-de-reportes-con-jasperrepots-y_30.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba a cambiar esa línea por lo siguiente:

```
im = JasperFillManager.fillReport("C:\\Users\\pc\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\proyecto7mo\\src\\Reportes\\ReporteVentas_1.jasper",
    parametros, conexion);
```

El problema es que no hay [ningún método que tenga la firma que tú intentas usar](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/api/net/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperFillManager.html#fillReport-java.lang.String-java.util.Map-java.sql.Connection-).

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que usas una conexion, para que? si estas intentanto pasar parametros, debes sacar la conexion y agregar new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lista) donde la lista serian tus colleciones de datos que deseas pasar, ademas puedes mejorar la ruta del jasper con report = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObjectFromFile(new File("").getAbsolutePath()+"/src/pdfs/parametros.jasper"); o usar la propiedad (user.dir)+"src/pdfs/parametros.jasper").